# sqlite3_exec function ignores sql buildup function value

Tags: c

I got the following sql_buildup_method... code is bit dirty but that s not the case

```
char *build_up_sql(char *inputName,char *inputMessage)
{
   char firstPartStatement[1064] ="INSERT INTO User (name, msg) VALUES (";
    char *endPartStatement =");";
    char *lightener = "'";  
    char *statement;

strcat(firstPartStatement,lightener);
strcat(firstPartStatement,inputName);
strcat(firstPartStatement,lightener);
strcat(firstPartStatement,",");
strcat(firstPartStatement,lightener);
strcat(firstPartStatement,inputMessage);
strcat(firstPartStatement,lightener);
strcat(firstPartStatement,endPartStatement);

statement = firstPartStatement; 

return statement;

}

void create_input(sqlite3 *handler,char *inputName,char *inputMessage)
{
    char *sql;

    sql = build_up_sql(inputName,inputMessage);
 // sql ="INSERT INTO User (name, msg) VALUES ('Susanne','hi all');";   
    printf("%s\n",sql);
    sqlite3_exec(handler,sql, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

the printf gives the output: INSERT INTO User (name, msg) VALUES ('Susanne','hi all'); which is totally fine ... but the sqlite3_exec ignores it and isn't generating new database input .... if I leave the line **sql ="INSERT INTO User (name, msg) VALUES ('Susanne','hi all');";** in the code the sqlite3_exec just works fine .... also putting everything in one function also solved the problem, but this shouldn't be an option.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are returning a pointer to a local variable, which is *undefined behavior*. When `build_up_sql` returns, the space on the stack for the local variables are reused.

The best solution is probably to add a parameter to `build_up_sql` that you use to put the string in. Something like:

```
char *build_up_sql(char *inputName, char *inputMessage, char *outputSql)
{
    const char firstPartStatement[] = "INSERT INTO User (name, msg) VALUES (";
    const char endPartStatement[] = ");";
    const char lightener[] = "'";

    strcpy(outputSql, firstPartStatement);
    strcat(outputSql,lightener);
    strcat(outputSql,inputName);
    strcat(outputSql,lightener);
    strcat(outputSql,",");
    strcat(outputSql,lightener);
    strcat(outputSql,inputMessage);
    strcat(outputSql,lightener);
    strcat(outputSql,endPartStatement);

    return outputSql;
}

void create_input(sqlite3 *handler, char *inputName, char *inputMessage)
{
    char sql[1024];

    char *sqlstr = build_up_sql(inputName, inputMessage, sql);

    printf("%s\n", sqlstr);
    sqlite3_exec(handler, sqlstr, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: it works....thank u very much... I really appreciate it.... I am just curious... I understand what you mean, but why do I get in the printf the correct String ?

Comment: @Fendrix Pure luck it works! :) Probably the stack hasn't been overwritten yet, so that's why it works in the `printf` call, but that call _do_ overwrite the stack so the next call will not work.

Comment: thx... if I would have a reputation score over 15 I would vote ur answer as usefull ... but I am still on 14, so sorry ....:)